# Reconfigurable function variables

Tags: go

I'm interested in reassigning factory functions for testing reasons within Go, to mitigate the risk of using a factory function within a given package when wanting to mock one of its types.

I've seen people pass factory functions as arguments to a containing function, and creating a struct that holds factories as data members. Is it instead possible to keep a top-level function variable and someway overwrite one implementation with another within a given file? I've tried the below:

```
type AirportFactory func (string, int, int) Airport

var makeAirport AirportFactory = func(n string, x int, y int) Airport {
    return airport{name: n, pos: Position{X: x, Y: y}}
}

makeAirport = func(n string, x int, y int) Airport {
    return airport{name:"default", pos:Position{X:0, Y:0}}
}
```

But when I build the code, 6g gives me the following error on the closing line of the last assignment:
`non-declaration statement outside function body`

This makes it seem like `var`s of function types are const, at least at the top level. Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not constant. You just can not assign to an already declared variable outside of a function. Something such as this will work:

```
func changeAirport() {
    makeAirport = func(n string, x int, y int) Airport {
        return airport{name:"default", pos:Position{X:0, Y:0}}
    }
}
```

As far as go is concerned, the variable assignments outside of a function do not happen in any particular order. As a consequence, you can only do it once.

Comment: Ah, that's very good to know. Definitely different than C/C++, but probably a very good decision now that I think of it; top-level ordering not being important has had many more pros than cons from what I've seen so far. I'm going to verify this when I hit my terminal.

Comment: @matthias, it's significantly different only from C++ as [in C++ it's just a feature, broken by design](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/ctors.html#fqa-10.12). C does not allow initialization of global variables with non-constant values, and the linker catches cases of multiple assignments to the same variable in different translation units.  So I'd say Go behaves pretty much like C here.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the package [init](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution) function to set the mock value of package variables. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

var x = 1

// set mock values of variables
func mock() {
    x = 2
}

func init() {
    mock()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Output:

```
2
```

For your example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Position struct {
    X int
    Y int
}
type Airport struct {
    name string
    pos  Position
}

type AirportFactory func(string, int, int) Airport

var makeAirport AirportFactory = func(n string, x int, y int) Airport {
    return Airport{name: n, pos: Position{X: x, Y: y}}
}

// set mock values of variables
func mock() {
    makeAirport = func(n string, x int, y int) Airport {
        return Airport{name: "default", pos: Position{X: 0, Y: 0}}
    }
}

func init() {
    mock()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(makeAirport("name", 1, 1))
}
```

Output:

```
{default {0 0}}
```

Comment: I presume that would work for func variables as well? I'll check when I get back to my terminal.

Comment: I would just like to add that `A package may contain multiple init functions, even within a single source file; they execute in unspecified order.` Be careful if you have another init function in the same package.